# equivalent to 'my Liver lobes'

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

In arabic, the organ 'the liver' has a noticeable role in language as does 'the heart'.
For example,
We say, in the heart of the city.

But we also say,
Zuhr prayer begins when the sun is at the liver of the sky. 
You hit the liver of the truth.
It may sound kind of odd in english.

It does not only limit to this, a man may call his lover, his liver, it is very common.
Or the verb in arabic, he is 'livered'. He is so in love/head over heels for her.

Also, and this is my question, father's say, my children are the lobes of my liver. It is a figurative phrase meaning 'my beloved everything'. A person can live without a portion of his liver, unlike his heart, but with many complications. The liver is an important organ. Maybe the father if he lost one of his liver lobes/one of his children, something will always embitter him in life, maybe that is where it comes from. Is there a common thing which children are described as in english by there parents?

Example:
Arabic poetry:
The incoming air, brought along the scent of my homeland, 
The land of my forefathers,
Where fuelled fire of malice burnt my liver lobes.

Comment: Note to save others looking it up: [*Zuhr*](http://www.iccuk.org/page.php?section=religious&page=timetableguide) begins just after the sun's zenith for the day.

Comment: In English traditions, the liver (like the kidneys) commands very little such adoration.  It's ironic, too.  The liver is no less necessary and perhaps more essential.  The liver is the seat of our metabolism and homeostasis.  However, apparently very little of that was in the minds of Shakespeare and Keats when they were looking for metaphors.

Comment: Until _very_ recently, the loss of part of the liver was not realistically survivable.

Answer (score 3):

**The apple of my eye.**

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_of_my_eye) is very thorough:

> *Apple of my eye*
>
> The phrase apple of my eye refers to something or someone that one
>   cherishes above all others.
>
> *Origin* [and derivation]
>
> The earliest appearance of the word is found in King Aelfred's writing
>   in ninth century. Before it means "favorite," it was literally meaning
>   "aperture at the center of the human eye" which means the pupil.
>
> Shakespeare also used it in the 1590s when he wrote A Midsummer
>   Night's Dream:
>
> "Flower of this purple dye, / Hit with Cupid's archery, / Sink in
>   apple of his eye".
>
> It also appears in the King James Bible Translation from 1611:
>
> Deuteronomy 32:10
>
> He found him in a desert land, and in the waste howling wilderness; he
>   led him about, he instructed him, he kept him as the apple of his eye.
>
> in the Book of Psalms 17:8
>
> Keep me as the apple of the eye, hide me under the shadow of thy wings
>
> in Proverbs 7:2
>
> Keep my commandments, and live; and my law as the apple of thine eye.
>
> Lamentations 2: 18
>
> Their heart cried unto the Lord, O wall of the daughter of Zion, let
>   tears run down like a river day and night: give thyself no rest; let
>   not the apple of thine eye cease.
>
> as well as in Zechariah 2:8
>
> For thus saith the LORD of hosts; After the glory hath he sent me unto
>   the nations which spoiled you: for he that toucheth you toucheth the
>   apple of his eye.
>
> The original Hebrew for this idiom, in all but Zechariah 2:8, was
>   'iyshown 'ayin (אישון עין), and can be literally translated as "Little
>   Man of the Eye." This is a reference to the tiny reflection of
>   yourself that you can see in other people's pupils. Other KJV
>   translations of the word 'iyshown include dark and obscure, as a
>   reference to the darkness of the pupil.
>
> This Hebrew idiom is surprisingly close to the Latin version, pupilla,
>   which means a little doll, and is a diminutive form of pupus, boy, or
>   pupa, girl (the source also for our other sense of pupil to mean a
>   schoolchild.) It was applied to the dark central portion of the eye
>   within the iris because of the tiny image of oneself, like a puppet or
>   marionette, that one can see when looking into another person's eye.
>
> In Zechariah 2:8, the Hebrew phrase used is bava 'ayin (בבה עין). The
>   meaning of bava is disputed. It may mean "apple"; and if so, the
>   phrase used in Zechariah 2:8 literally refers to the "apple of the
>   eye." However, it appears that most Hebrew scholars think this Hebrew
>   phrase communicated the meaning conveyed by the English word,
>   "eyeball" (E.g., see The Hebrew and Aramaic Lexicon of the Old
>   Testament, vol. 1, p. 107).
>
> The phrase is also used in Sir Walter Scott's Old Mortality, 1816:
>
> "Poor Richard was to me as an eldest son, the apple of my eye."

Answer (score -1):

"The fruits of my loins" - this would be the equivalent I believe.

Comment: I would disagree; fruit of my loins indicates offspring, but does not generally indicate positive or negative attachment to them.